# Do CPU cores within VMs benefit from hardware-based encryption?

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, encryption, linux-kvm

I am running Proxmox and some VMs on it. I want to set up an nginx proxy that would take care of SSL offloading for all of my services. I am wondering if running it on one of the VMs would mean there would be no hardware-based encryption, impacting the performance severely, as opposed to running it directly on the host.
When I view `/proc/cpuinfo` on the host, I see these entries:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 113
model name  : AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x8701021
cpu MHz     : 3352.873
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 6
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 13
initial apicid  : 13
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 16
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate sme ssbd mba sev ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca
bugs        : sysret_ss_attrs spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips    : 7187.19
TLB size    : 3072 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro [13] [14]
```

`/proc/cpuinfo` in the VM shows a lot less flags, namely the `aes` flag is missing too.

```
processor   : 5
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Common KVM processor
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x1000065
cpu MHz     : 3593.248
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx lm rep_good nopl cpuid extd_apicid tsc_known_freq pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor cmp_legacy 3dnowprefetch vmmcall
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs swapgs_fence spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 7186.49
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after conducting some testing. My setup: proxmox box with some VMs and LXC containers. Initially I set up my proxy within one of the VMs. Performance did suffer greatly with a virtualized processor. After I put the proxy into an LXC container on proxmox, removing the KVM layer of virtualization, I tried uploading a 7GB iso on proxmox. the speed was absolutely blazing fast while an nginx worker process utilized 50% of one core, while when in a VM, the nginx worker process would take up a whole core with speeds several times slower.

edit:
This is only the case when choosing the proxmox default CPU type - `kvm64`. After some additional digging, I found out that this is done by default to enable a live VM migration to a different host which might have a different CPU type. KVM emulated CPU has less flags, but is guaranteed to work everywhere.
The CPU type can be changed to `host` which will pass all the CPU flags through to the VM, thus enabling, among many others, a hardware-based encryption.
[source](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Qemu/KVM_Virtual_Machines)